# First String begins with second String in Racket language

Tags: string, racket

I'm designing a function that takes two Strings and returns a Boolean indicating whether the first string begins with the second in Racket language.

This is what I have right now:

```
(define (string-starts-with? s1 s2)
  (cond
  [(string=? s1 s2) #true]
  [else #false]))
```

Comment: The solution highly depends on what you learned earlier. Do you know functions like `string-length` and `substring`? This will give you one possible solution. On the other hand, do you know `string->list` and how to perform recursion over list? This will give you another possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a built-in procedure for that, you can use:

```
(define (string-starts-with? s1 s2)
  ; checks if s1 starts with s2
  (string-prefix? s1 s2))

(string-starts-with? "foobar" "foo")
=> #t
(string-starts-with? "foobar" "baz")
=> #f
```